# Hibernate define @Where annotation in super class

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I am trying to implement soft delete in my spring - hibernate project.
My plan is to override the delete method with the `@SQLDelete` annotation and filter the logical deleted entities with hibernate `@Where` annotation in my queries.

I experience some difficulties when I try to define the `@Where` clause in the super class, It's seems that the entities dont inherit the `@Where` clause from the abstract base class.

**Note:** If I move the `@Where` annotation to the entity class everything work as expected

**The base entity class:**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Where(clause = " IS_DELETED = false")
public abstract class BaseEntity {

   @Column(name = "IS_DELETED")
   private boolean isDeleted;

   public BaseEntity() {
   }

   public boolean getIsDeleted() {
      return this.isDeleted;
   }

   public void setIsDeleted(boolean isDeleted) {
      this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
   }
 }
```

**The entity class:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Events")
@SQLDelete(sql ="UPDATE events " +
                "SET IS_DELETED = true " +
                "WHERE id = ?")
public class Event extends BaseEntity {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "ID")
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "NAME")
   private String name;

   public Event() {
   }

   public Long getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public void setId(Long id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}
```

Thanks for any kind of help :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
@Where(clause = "IS_DELETED = 0")
```

or

```
@Where(clause = "isDeleted = 0")
```

?